# Handling InteractionSources from HorizontalPager and child content (design question)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, horizontal-pager

## Context

I am in the process of making a custom component that is similar to the [BannerAd](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) view. In my case, it is a fairly simple component that uses a `HorizontalPager` to display images. Here are the pertinent features I want my component to implement:

1. The pager will scroll automatically every couple of seconds.
2. If the user is pressing/dragging the image displayed the pager will temporarily stop the automatic scrolling.

## Question

I have found two different ways in which this can be implemented and was wondering if there was a best practice for these types of 'design' problems.

The first way is to observe only the `interactionState` of the `Image` composable inside the `HorizontalPager`. The only type of `Interaction` passed from the `interactionSource` state is of type `PressInteraction` (Press, Release, Cancel).

The second way is to observe the `interactionState` of the `Image` composable **and** the drag state of the pager. We still need to observe the `interactionState` of the `Image` as the pager does not provide information about state changes to `PressInteraction` (only `DragInteraction` is handled).

Approach number 1 seems simpler, where we seem to be implicitly relying on the fact that a drag event is a subset of a press event i.e. it's not possible to drag the banner without pressing an item first but approach number 2 seems more explicit in the type of events we are handling. Aside from readability, could performance be a consideration? Are there any other aspects I have neglected, which I should be concerned about? Or is there a completely different approach which would be better than both?

## Code

Approach number 1

```
@Composable
fun FoundationBanner(
    drawableResources: List<Int>,
) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(0)

    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val interactionState by interactionSource.interactions.collectAsState(initial = null)

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = interactionState) {
        if (interactionState !is PressInteraction.Press) {
            while (true) {
                delay(2000)
                pagerState.animateScrollToPage((pagerState.currentPage + 1) % drawableResources.size)
            }
        }
    }

    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        pageCount = drawableResources.size,
    ) { page ->
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = drawableResources[page]),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.clickable(interactionSource, null) {}
        )
    }
}
```

Approach number 2

```
@Composable
fun FoundationBanner(
    drawableResources: List<Int>,
) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(0)
    val pagerIsDragged by pagerState.interactionSource.collectIsDraggedAsState()

    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val interactionState by interactionSource.interactions.collectAsState(initial = null)

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = interactionState, key2 = pagerIsDragged) {
        if (!pagerIsDragged && interactionState !is PressInteraction.Press) {
            while (true) {
                delay(2000)
                pagerState.animateScrollToPage((pagerState.currentPage + 1) % drawableResources.size)
            }
        }
    }

    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        pageCount = drawableResources.size,
    ) { page ->
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = drawableResources[page]),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier.clickable(interactionSource, null) {}
        )
    }
}
```